# Correctly converting binary data to type from char *

Tags: c++, pointers, binary

I have an array of binary data that is in a fixed format, so the first 80 bytes are redundant, and then the next 4 bytes specify a number in uint32_t. So far I've tried a few different ways to get that number out, but I can't seem to access it correctly. Things I've tried:

```
char value[4];
memcpy(value, dataBuffer+80, 4);
cout << uint32_t(*value);

for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
{
   value[x] = dataBuffer[80+x];
}
cout << uint32_t(*value);
```

And a few other variations on the same. Ordinarily I just use Qt's `QDataStream` which abstracts it away, but I'm stumped at why those approaches aren't working.

The file format is little endian if that makes any difference.

Comment: I don't recommend using ellipses for code you're showing someone. We can't help you debug ellipses.

Comment: It's a bog standard for loop, but I'll amend.

Comment: See my answer, I've found your problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I do it is:

```
char value[4];
uint32_t num = 0;
memcpy(&num, &value[0], sizeof(uint32_t));
std::cout << num;
```

I'll assume you already know the potential issues regarding endianness.

Comment: That's got it! Thanks :) it looks like the method I was taking previously was only copying the *first* 4 byte group, which I verified by running the file through a hex viewer and comparing. Your solution works perfectly.

Comment: No, it is not that it was copying first 4 bytes, it is because of the wrong conversion.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

I have already typed this word today. Endianness. Did you conside this at all? I also assume, you meant memcpy and not memset.

Ok, I see that you are saying it is little endian. So when you say it doesn't work, are you sure the buffer you are receiving is little-endian? If it was sent over network by any type of decent application, it would be big-endian.

EDIT.

Ok, I see the problem, not sure why I missed it first time. Invalid conversion is made. Should be

```
*(uint32_t*)vaue
```

What you are doing now, you are printing numerical value of the first character.

Comment: Positive it's little endian, and yeah I meant memcpy not memset fixed in original post.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem. Missed it somehow :) Your conversion is not right. Should be *((uint32_t*)value)

Comment: Thanks! Benjamin got there just before you, but that's also a great solution, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If endianness is an important part of your question, I strongly advise you to read this great post from Rob Pike: http://commandcenter.blogspot.fr/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html

```
uint32_t ui =       (dataBuffer[80]<<0)
                |   (dataBuffer[81]<<8)
                |   (dataBuffer[82]<<16)
                |   (dataBuffer[83]<<24);
```

Comment: I wasn't sure whether it would be or not, so decided to include it, but that link looks like some awesome reading.